# Monitoring file changes pos and length

Tags: linux, monitoring

It is easy to monitor file changes with inotify.but Inotify can only reply IN_MODIFY event with file name and some file attr when I write to a file.How can I get the new add content's start pos and content length in the change file?Is there any api to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make additional script for watch inotify log and check for changes in some files list and then journaling size changes, Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in `cat /etc/inotify/special_files_list.conf`; do
   FOUND_CHANGES=`tail -n 10000 /var/log/inotify.log | grep `$cur_date_with_hour` | grep $n`
   PREVIOUS_FILE_SIZE=`/var/log/inotify-special.log | cut -d ';' -f 0`
   FILE_SIZE=stat -c "%s" `cut -d ';' -f 0,1`
   file_size_diff = `expr $PREVIOUS_FILE_SIZE - $FILE_SIZE`
   if [ file_size_diff !-eq 0 ]; then
      echo "$FOUND_CHANGES;" >> /var/log/inotify-special.log
   fi
done
...
```

Comment: I don't want to use diff or other checksum script to get the change content,I want to know is there any api get this from linux kernal or intercept in IO level such as drbd directly?

Comment: May be you can try to modify inotify if it's not very difficult to you and you really need this feature.